# "Accept Cookies" popup with Selenium in Python using explicit wait

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, iframe, css-selectors

I have been trying to webscrape some information from a webside with Selenium in Python. I load the webside, but I can't accept the cookies, which is necessary to continue. I have tried to use explicitly wait as I suspected that the problem was that the webside loaded before the "accept" bottom becomes clickable.

My code is:

```
import os
import until as until
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

os.environ['PATH'] += r"C:\Users\BackUp HDL\AppData\Local\Programs"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://watchmedier.dk/latest/filtered? sitesFilter=policywatch.dk&sitesFilter=shippingwatch.dk&sitesFilter=mobilitywatch.dk&sitesFilter=energiwatch.dk&sitesFilter=finanswatch.dk&sitesFilter=ejendomswatch.dk&sitesFilter=mediawatch.dk&sitesFilter=agriwatch.dk&sitesFilter=fodevarewatch.dk&sitesFilter=medwatch.dk&sitesFilter=kapwatch.dk&sitesFilter=itwatch.dk&sitesFilter=ctwatch.dk&sitesFilter=watchmedier.dk&sitesFilter=advokatwatch.dk")

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="notice"]/div[3]/button[2]')))
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="notice"]/div[3]/button[2]').click()
```

Whenever I try to run the code I get an error. Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element <kbd>Accepter</kbd> is within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

    ```
    driver.get("https://watchmedier.dk/latest/filtered? sitesFilter=policywatch.dk&sitesFilter=shippingwatch.dk&sitesFilter=mobilitywatch.dk&sitesFilter=energiwatch.dk&sitesFilter=finanswatch.dk&sitesFilter=ejendomswatch.dk&sitesFilter=mediawatch.dk&sitesFilter=agriwatch.dk&sitesFilter=fodevarewatch.dk&sitesFilter=medwatch.dk&sitesFilter=kapwatch.dk&sitesFilter=itwatch.dk&sitesFilter=ctwatch.dk&sitesFilter=watchmedier.dk&sitesFilter=advokatwatch.dk")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[title='SP Consent Message']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[title='Accepter']"))).click()
    ```
  - Using *XPATH*:

    ```
    driver.get("https://watchmedier.dk/latest/filtered? sitesFilter=policywatch.dk&sitesFilter=shippingwatch.dk&sitesFilter=mobilitywatch.dk&sitesFilter=energiwatch.dk&sitesFilter=finanswatch.dk&sitesFilter=ejendomswatch.dk&sitesFilter=mediawatch.dk&sitesFilter=agriwatch.dk&sitesFilter=fodevarewatch.dk&sitesFilter=medwatch.dk&sitesFilter=kapwatch.dk&sitesFilter=itwatch.dk&sitesFilter=ctwatch.dk&sitesFilter=watchmedier.dk&sitesFilter=advokatwatch.dk")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@title='SP Consent Message']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@title='Accepter']"))).click()
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: Watchmedier]

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe/53276478#53276478)
- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. The code worked. Now I'm just stuck at a new problem as I'm totally new at using both Python and Selenium. I guess, my skill level simply isn't great enough to extract data in this way. Do you now if there is someone I can contact for more help, since I need the data for my master?

Comment: Of coarse, feel free to discuss with me at length in [Selenium](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium) room.